# jQuery eq not working in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following js:

```
$('.overlayWrap').on('click', '.overlaySwitch', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $overlayRegisterWrap = $('.overlayRegisterWrap li'),
        type = $(this).data('go');

        event.preventDefault();
        $overlayRegisterWrap.hide();
        $overlayRegisterWrap.eq(type).show();
});
```

It works in firefox, chrome and safari but as soon as I try it on mobile it hides all the li's but then does not show the proper li. If I console log out `$overlayRegisterWrap.eq(type)` it finds the right li but does not display it. I am completely lost. Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT
Here is the basic html structure:

```
<div id="Overlay" style="" class="overlayWrap" focus="">
    <ul class="overlayRegisterWrap">
        <li style="display: none;">
            //some crazy code
            <a class="overlaySwitch" data-go="1">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none;">
            //some crazy code
            <a class="overlaySwitch" data-go="2">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none;">
            //some crazy code
            <a class="overlaySwitch" data-go="3">Next</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none;">
            //some crazy code
            <a class="overlaySwitch" data-go="1">Forgot</a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: none;">
            //some crazy code
            <a class="overlaySwitch" data-go="2">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your markup ? what is the value of `data-go` ?

Comment: there is a lot but I put up the basic

Comment: OK, where is `.overlaySwitch` ?

Comment: please show all the relevant code... not just a bit of it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a string to [`jQuery.fn.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), but it only accepts numbers. You've to *"convert"* the data-value to an integer. In your case the following should do the trick:

```
$('.overlayWrap').on('click', '.overlaySwitch', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $overlayRegisterWrap = $('.overlayRegisterWrap li'),
        type = $(this).data('go') << 0; // We you the bitwise operatir to parse the data-string to an integer

        event.preventDefault();
        $overlayRegisterWrap.hide();
        $overlayRegisterWrap.eq(type).show();
});
```